# Codigo Js a React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola realice una funcionalidad en `javascript`, la cual al hacer `hover` por una `card` y mover el mouse fuera de ella esta se mantiene, y solo se quita cuando hago `hover` en otra `card` el codigo es el siguiente:

```js
var card1 = document.querySelector('.card1');
var card2 = document.querySelector('.card2');

function addHoverClass(element) {
  element.classList.add("hover");
}
card1.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
card2.classList.remove('hover');
});

card2.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
card1.classList.remove('hover');
  
});
```

```css
.card {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF416C, #FF4B2B);
color: white;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.card::before,
.card::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 50%;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.card.hover::before,
.card.hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.card:hover::before,
.card.hover::before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.card:hover::after,
.card.hover::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.card::before {
left: 0;
transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.card::after {
right: 0;
transform: translateX(100%);
}

.card:hover::before {
transform: translateX(0);
}

.card:hover::after {
transform: translateX(0);
}

.additional-text {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
color: white;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
display: none;
}

.card:hover .additional-text,
.card.hover .additional-text {
display: block;
}

.card1.hover .additional-text {
display: block;
}

.card2.hover .additional-text {
display: block;
}.card:hover .additional-text,
.card.hover .additional-text {
  display: block;
}

.card1.hover .additional-text {
  display: block;
}

.card2.hover .additional-text {
  display: block;
}
.card2.hover > h2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.card1.hover > h2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="card card1" onmouseenter="addHoverClass(this)">
  <h2>Mi carta</h2>
  <span class="additional-text">Texto adicional</span>
</div>
<br/>

<div class="card card2" onmouseenter="addHoverClass(this)">
  <h2 class="mostrar">Mi carta</h2>
  <span class="additional-text">Texto adicional</span>
</div>
```

Estoy intentando aplicar esto mismo pero con `react`, pero me encuentro con el problema de que la funcionalidad de arriba pues esta con 2 elementos `cards` separados, y en `react` quiero tener un solo componente para varias `cards` y que funcione de esa manera.

Este es mi componente

```
const MisionVision = ({
  contenido_titulo,
  contenido_titulo_ver,
  contenido_imagen,
  contenido_descripcion,
  contenido_vermas,
  contenido_enlace,
  contenido_id,
}) => {


  return (
    <div
      className={`cardContainer-Mision class-${contenido_id}`}
    >
      <div
        className={`card-Mision ${
          contenido_titulo === "Misión"
            ? "mision"
            : contenido_titulo === "Visión"
            ? "vision"
            : ""
        }`}
      >
        <div className="card-overlay-Mision"></div>
        {contenido_titulo === "Misión" || contenido_titulo === "Visión" ? (
          ""
        ) : (
          <h2 className="card-text-Mision">{contenido_titulo}</h2>
        )}
        )
        <span className="additional-text-Mision">
          {window.HTMLReactParser(contenido_descripcion)}
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

He intentado agregar una clase especial para cada uno pero no logro aplicarlo bien, use `href` y `current` para validar si la clase era la de una carta o la otra, y logro poner la clase `hover` pero no logro que cuando se haga `hover` a la otra `card` se remueva la clase de la que estaba activa.

Comment: Yo tendría un componente card y luego otro componente que admita una colección de cards. Es más fácil modelar clases pequeñas y luego, por composición, crear clases "contenedoras"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograr la funcionalidad que estás buscando agregando un estado al componente `MisionVision` que indique qué carta está en modo `hover` en un momento dado.

Luego, puedes usar una función manejadora de eventos para cambiar el estado cuando se hace `hover` en una carta y otra función para agregar la clase hover a la carta actualmente en modo hover.

```js
import {
  useState
} from 'react';

const MisionVision = ({
  contenido_titulo,
  contenido_titulo_ver,
  contenido_imagen,
  contenido_descripcion,
  contenido_vermas,
  contenido_enlace,
  contenido_id,
}) => {
  const [hoveredCard, setHoveredCard] = useState(null);

  const handleCardHover = (id) => {
    setHoveredCard(id);
  };

  const addHoverClass = (id) => {
    const cards = document.querySelectorAll(`.class-${id}`);
    cards.forEach((card) => {
      card.classList.add('hover');
    });

    if (hoveredCard && hoveredCard !== id) {
      const previousCards = document.querySelectorAll(`.class-${hoveredCard}`);
      previousCards.forEach((card) => {
        card.classList.remove('hover');
      });
    }
  };

  return ( <
    div className = {
      `cardContainer-Mision class-${contenido_id}`
    } >
    <
    div className = {
      `card-Mision ${
          contenido_titulo === 'Misión'
            ? 'mision'
            : contenido_titulo === 'Visión'
            ? 'vision'
            : ''
        }`
    }
    onMouseEnter = {
      () => handleCardHover(contenido_id)
    } >
    <
    div className = "card-overlay-Mision" > < /div> {
      contenido_titulo === 'Misión' || contenido_titulo === 'Visión' ? (
        ''
      ) : ( <
        h2 className = "card-text-Mision" > {
          contenido_titulo
        } < /h2>
      )
    } <
    span className = "additional-text-Mision" > {
      window.HTMLReactParser(contenido_descripcion)
    } <
    /span> <
    /div> <
    style jsx > {
      `
        .hover {
          /* styles for when the card is hovered */
        }
      `
    } < /style> <
    /div>
  );
};
```

Lo que hice fue que el estado `hoveredCard` es inicializado en `null`. La función `handleCardHover` es llamada cuando se hace hover en una carta y actualiza el estado `hoveredCard` con el id de esa carta.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que en el ejemplo anterior se está usando querySelectorAll para seleccionar todas las cartas con la clase `class-${id}` y `class-${hoveredCard}`, lo cual puede afectar el rendimiento en caso de que haya muchas cartas. Si este es el caso, podrías considerar otras opciones de selección de elementos más eficientes, como usar `data-attributes` para identificar cada carta.

Comment: En donde estas utilizando el `addHoverClass` ?

Comment: En tu código JS inicial. Lo que podrías hacer es mantener un estado en el componente para saber qué tarjeta está siendo "hovered" en un momento dado y luego aplicar la clase "hover" solo a esa tarjeta.

Por ejemplo, podrías agregar el siguiente estado en tu componente:


const [hoveredCard, setHoveredCard] = useState(null);

Comment: Luego, podrías agregar un controlador de eventos onMouseEnter a cada tarjeta que establezca el estado hoveredCard con el id de la tarjeta actual:

<div
  className={`cardContainer-Mision class-${contenido_id}`}
  onMouseEnter={() => setHoveredCard(contenido_id)}
>